# Pandas dataframe update keys

Tags: python, pandas

I'm unable to update a Pandas `Dataframe` using `pd.update()` function, I always get a `None` result. 
I'm using a `Dataframe` with keys which is the result of joining 2 `Dataframes`.

I calculate the `z1 score` for only `float32` columns, and then I update the `Dataframe` with the new values for `float32` columns.

```
class MySimpleScaler(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self._means = None
    self._stds = None

  def preprocess(self, data):
    """Calculate z-score for dataframe"""
    if self._means is None: # During training only
      self._means = data.select_dtypes('float32').mean()
    if self._stds is None: # During training only
      self._stds = data.select_dtypes('float32').std()
      if not self._stds.all():
        raise ValueError('At least one column has standard deviation of 0.')
    z1 = (data.select_dtypes('float32') - self._means) / self._stds
    return data.update(z1)
```

```
all_x = pd.concat([train_x, eval_x], keys=['train', 'eval'])
scaler = MySimpleScaler()
all_x = scaler.preprocess(all_x)
train_x, eval_x = all_x.xs('train'), all_x.xs('eval')
```

When I run the `data.update(z1)` it always returns `None`.

I need to reuse the scaler object later to calculate z score for new dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add to a set, you are doing an in-place operation, which returns `None`. The Series will be updated, but the copy returned will be `None`.

Answer (score 1):

DataFrame [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) is an in-place operation. It will always return `None`, but the dataframe will be modified.